# SharePoint 2013 - Client Side Rendering Context variable

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a question regarding the client side rendering in SharePoint 2013.

In solutions of the internet I often found things like that:

```
var ctx = {};
ctx.Templates = {};
ctx.Templates.Fields = {
    'Aktionsliste': {
        'NewForm': renderTaskCategory
    }
};
```

I understand that this code is affecting the field 'Aktionsliste' when opening the 'NewForm'. When opening the 'NewForm' the function 'renderTaskCategory' is executed. What I don't understand is the meaning of those lines, where the "{}" are included. What does it mean, when "ctx" or "ctx.Templates" get the value '{}'? Does the first line for example mean that the variable ctx now uses the current SP.ClientContext of the page?

Regards
André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's use to initialize an object in javascript.

**{}** syntax is exactly the same than **new Object()**